# Is there any way to export a Google Visualization org chart as an image?

Tags: image, export, google-visualization, orgchart

Is there anyway to have an export function to export the [Google Visualization  organizational chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html) as an image?  I want this as a feature of my website, so people can click a button or a link and have it save as an image or a pdf file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a screen-shot of the browser. There are multiples tools out there to do this. We used this: http://code.google.com/p/speak-lib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/WebShot%3Fstate%3Dclosed

It works fine. We generate previews of design changes that way.

Comment: i need this to be something that can be done by any user as a feature of the site . .

Comment: Show the chart with an export button to the user, 
if the user clicks on the "export" button, you make the screen-shot of another browser instance (its just an library call) - and you are done. It does not scale great, but it works.

Comment: here's a link to the actual code that makes the screenshot: http://code.google.com/p/speak-lib/source/browse/trunk/SpeakLib.Utilities/Service/Imaging/WebScreenshotGenerator.cs

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/speak-lib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/WebShot%3Fstate%3Dclosed not found

Comment: Hi @NunoMarinho, the sources relocated to https://github.com/teamaton/speak-lib/tree/master/WebShot.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://phantomjs.org/ you can write script to cut your web page into PNG images of some fixed size and then assemble them into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the SVG code and send it to a server to convert it to an image. This is a scalable and easy solution. Answer details here: [Convert Google Geochart to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) or PDF in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546192/convert-google-geochart-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-or-pdf-in-the-browser/18440371#18440371)

Answer (score 0):

Use `chart.getImageURI()` it gives the image location