# Getting URL of Google Visualization Image Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So what I am trying to do is get the URL of a Google Visualization IMAGE Chart (not SVG version).

To create the chart, I am using this code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['imagelinechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Value'], 

 ['5:00', 13535],['5:30', 13549]
 ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ImageLineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 750, height: 240, legend: 'none', title: 'TITLE'});


  }


  </script>
```

This creates the image in a  but I am unable to get the URL inside of a variable. (Yes I can obviously copy the image after the page has loaded and get the URL)

I have tried:

```
 chart.getImageURL()
```

..but did not have any luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is a big problem for me.

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Google Visualization Charts are not rendered as images, and cannot be saved as images as default behavior. It is possible to create a function that will save the SVG chart as a PNG image, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546192).

This can be done by following the steps on [this page](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html). Note that the code in the article is based on an old version of Google Visualization which used iframes, and will not work as posted. However, you can do the same using the following code (found in the comments):

```
var svg = $(chartContainer).find('svg').parent().html();
var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; ' + '');
doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvg(canvas, svg);
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
return imgData;
```

Note: I did not create this code, it was originally created by the author of the above site (Riccardo Govoni) and updated in the comments section by user Thomas.